# Distributing points over a surface within boundries

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I'm interested in a way (algorithm) of distributing a predefined number of points over a 4 sided surface like a square.

The main issue is that each point has got to have a minimum and maximum proximity to each other (random between two predefined values). Basically the distance of any two points should not be closer than let's say 2, and a further than 3.

My code will be implemented in ruby (the points are locations, the surface is a map), but any ideas or snippets are definitely welcomed as all my ideas include a fair amount of brute force.

Comment: how is this a programming question? It's a 'tell me an algorithm' question...

Comment: Programming is very related to algorithms.

Comment: @Mitch Did you read the last line? You seem rather grumpy today. :/

Comment: I'm working on an open source game. I'm tring to generate a map; I need to have each location spread similar to the pattern I described.

Comment: @marcog: did you read that last line? where's the code? question is asking for an algorithm. Suggest you try the CS SO site.

Comment: @Mitch Have you seen how many questions contain no code here?

Comment: Does it need to look random? What does maximum proximity mean in this case - proximity to nearest neighbor or farthest neighbor?

Comment: @marcog: and that makes them OK?

Comment: @Mitch No, but it sure as hell is a strong sign that such a question is acceptable here!

Comment: @marcog: I vote how I see fit. That's not going to change. Poster has clearly left out his real question, which he has now posted in comments. SO has too many questions which are asking for a an answer to a perceived solution, rather than the actual problem the poster is facing.

Comment: @kotlinski: Really? after 25 years as a programmer, I'd never realised that. ;)

Comment: @kotlinski, basically it should not be closer than let's say 2 and further than 3. While I would like it to look random anything that works it's good enough for me.

Comment: @vise: If you don't need it to look random, the easiest solution probably is to just space out all dots in a hexagonal grid with distance 2.

Comment: @Mitch You're being guilty of the very thing you're picking OP out on here, but in a different way. First you say "how is this a programming question?", now you're saying it's "left out his real question". You left out your real reason for not liking this question.

Comment: @marcog: I have no further interest discussing with you.

Comment: @kotlinski thank you for the advice. Most likely this is what I'll end up using (the minimum for my tests to pass), until I can polish it up at a later date.

Comment: Borderline on topic.  Added ruby tag since OP prefers Ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [this paper](http://diwww.epfl.ch/w3lsp/publications/colour/prhsfcabp_93.html). It has a nice, intuitive algorithm that does what you need.

> In our modelization, we adopted another model: we consider each center to be related to all its neighbours by a repulsive string.
>
> At the beginning of the simulation, the centers are randomly distributed, as well as the strengths of the
>   strings. We choose randomly to move one center; then we calculate the resulting force caused by all
>   neighbours of the given center, and we calculate the displacement which is proportional and oriented
>   in the sense of the resulting force.
>
> After a certain number of iterations (which depends on the number of
>   centers and the degree of initial randomness) the system becomes stable.

In case it is not clear from the figures, this approach generates uniformly distributed points. You may use instead a force that is zero inside your bounds (between 2 and 3, for example) and non-zero otherwise (repulsive if the points are too close, attractive if too far).

This is my Python implementation (sorry, I don´t know ruby). Just import this and call uniform() to get a list of points.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm
import pylab as pl

# find the nearest neighbors (brute force)
def neighbors(x, X, n=10):
  dX = X - x
  d = dX[:,0]**2 + dX[:,1]**2
  idx = np.argsort(d)
  return X[idx[1:11]]

# repulsion force, normalized to 1 when d == rmin
def repulsion(neib, x, d, rmin):
  if d == 0:
    return np.array([1,-1])

  return 2*(x - neib)*rmin/(d*(d + rmin))

def attraction(neib, x, d, rmax):
  return rmax*(neib - x)/(d**2)

def uniform(n=25, rmin=0.1, rmax=0.15):
  # Generate randomly distributed points
  X = np.random.random_sample( (n, 2) )

  # Constants
  # step is how much each point is allowed to move
  #   set to a lower value when you have more points
  step = 1./50.

  # maxk is the maximum number of iterations
  #   if step is too low, then maxk will need to increase
  maxk = 100

  k = 0

  # Force applied to the points
  F = np.zeros(X.shape)

  # Repeat for maxk iterations or until all forces are zero
  maxf = 1.
  while maxf > 0 and k < maxk:
    maxf = 0
    for i in xrange(n):
      # Force calculation for the i-th point
      x = X[i]
      f = np.zeros(x.shape)

      # Interact with at most 10 neighbors
      Neib = neighbors(x, X, 10)

      # dmin is the distance to the nearest neighbor
      dmin = norm(Neib[0] - x)

      for neib in Neib:
        d = norm(neib - x)
        if d < rmin:
          # feel repulsion from points that are too near
          f += repulsion(neib, x, d, rmin)
        elif dmin > rmax:
          # feel attraction if there are no neighbors closer than rmax
          f += attraction(neib, x, d, rmax)

      # save all forces and the maximum force to normalize later
      F[i] = f
      if norm(f) <> 0:
        maxf = max(maxf, norm(f))

    # update all positions using the forces
    if maxf > 0:
      X += (F/maxf)*step

    k += 1

  if k == maxk:
    print "warning: iteration limit reached"

  return X
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume that one of your brute force ideas includes just repeatedly generating points at random and checking to see if the constraints happen to be satisified.

Another way is to take a configuration that satisfies the constraints and repeatedly perturb a small part of it, chosen at random - for instance move a single point - to move to a randomly chosen nearby configuration. If you do this often enough you should move to a random configuration that is almost independent of the starting point. This could be justified under http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_sampling.

Answer (score 1):

I might try just doing it at random, then going through and dropping points that are to close to other points. You can compare the square of the distance to save some math time.

Or create cells with borders and place a point in each one. Less random, it depends on if this is a "just for looks thing" or not. But it could be very fast.

Answer (score 0):

I made a compromise and ended up using the Poisson Disk Sampling method.

The result was fairly close to what I needed, especially with a lower number of tries (which also drastically reduces cost).