# Fast Dictionary Comparison by key, but value within a range of primary Dicationarys Value

Tags: python

Just wondering if anyone can provide me some insight.

I have the following code that generates random positions on my screen, (basically it is positioning around 200 images)

right now the images can have the same co-ord's or very close, my goal is to check the current position generated to previously generated positions(to be stored in the _positioncheck dictionary) and if they overlap or are within the 50% range then  skip and regenerate again.

apologies if I have not made this very clear :/, if any other info is needed I can re-edit.

```
def generateposhint(self):
        global _positioncheck
        xf =0
        yf = 0
        self.position = None

        xf = random.uniform(0.0,0.9)
        yf = random.uniform(0.0,0.9)
        self.position = {'x':xf,'y':yf}
        for items in _positioncheck:
```

code to be completed here

```
        #print position

        return self.position
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581372

Comment: Cheers Emilio, Will give that a read over with links, very similar, random placement, and to be within a certain range of each other. Nice Find :)

Comment: maybe the simplest way for me, would be to draw a grid of 10 x 10, but its with floats, does python have float range function?

Comment: `numpy.arange(...)` can produce a range of floats.